# How to get the class from which a request originates in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

My modules all extend Backend controller which checks if loggedin and redirects appropriately, now I have Class FrontEnd [responsible for pages like login, signup etc] which extends My_Controller. 
how can I create an exemption for FrontEnd to be able to access the modules since it needs their methods to perform tasks.

this is what I have currently ....

```
class Backend_Controller extends MY_Controller {

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->checkLoggedIn();
    }

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public function checkLoggedIn() {
        //check if loggedin
        if (!$this->auth->loggedIn()) {
            //implement exclusion for FrontEnd class to allow access to methods though not        logged in
            if (!the class trying to access == 'FrontEnd') { //how to get refferal page
                return;
            } else {
                redirect('login');
            }
        }
    }
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
}
```

how can I get "the class trying to access == 'FrontEnd" 
Edditional Info:
the FrontEnd class generates a form which has an 
`enter code here`action= router->fetch_class() will result in someMoudleName ,
but what i want is for  it to be able to detect that the action is coming from FrontEnd Class

Comment: `$this->router->fetch_class();`

Comment: @Nouphal.M thanks, but I already tried that, but it doesnt solve my problem. please see the edited code to understand better. the FrontEnd class generates a form which has an action= <?php echo site_url('someMoudleName/someMethod'); so $this->router->fetch_class() will result in someMoudleName ,but what i want is for  it to be able to detect that the action is coming from FrontEnd Class

Comment: if you need the mthod name then you can access it via `$this->router->fetch_method();`

Comment: @Nouphal.M please check my edit, the FrontEnd Class makes a remote call to a module/method which extends BackEnd_Controller. I need BackEnd_Controller to be able to detect that the call is coming from FrontEnd class.I am not interested in the call itself, but the originating class.

Comment: please vote my question up

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will depend on your url but u can do something like this..

```
 function getNameOfOriginatingClass{
     $this->load->library('user_agent');
     $previous_url = $this->agent->referrer();
     $url_segments = explode('/',$previous_url);
     echo '<pre>';print_r($url_segments);    
 }
```

after printing this result u can see your link broken into parts in an array.. Normally the $url_segments[3] or $url_segments[4] will contain your previous function name and previous one will contain previous class name depending upon your url.

Comment: Thanks @BaD Developer. but i had to edit your answer. This section should actually be $url_segments = explode('/', $previous_url );